# How do I find this limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ n-{n\over e}\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n \right]$?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

I'm working on a practice exam for my masters quals and I am having difficulties with the following limit. According to wolfram alpha, it's value is 1/2. Does anyone know how to find this limit?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ n-{n\over e}\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n \right].$$

Comment: Can you use L'Hospital's Rule?

Comment: [This table may help you study for your exam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms). It tells you how to transform the indeterminates to easier forms.

Comment: Are you sure that you posted a right problem?

Comment: I canceled e with $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ and editied .

Comment: Also, delete $n$ in the title

Comment: If you add one term to the expansion, you should get $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{11}{24 n}+\frac{7}{16   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$ which for $n=10$ gives $\frac{2201}{4800}\approx 0.458542$

Comment: I don't see your response.

Comment: @zhw. I appeared in an entrance exam. This question would've helped me pas it.Sorry I was off for a while.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706711/limit-exists-or-not-lim-limits-n-to-infty-leftn-fracne-left1-fr.

Comment: @StubbornAtom bhai rank?

Comment: See also:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1706711
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3107466
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3534946

Comment: This question is about similar limit: [Limit of $x\left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x - e\right)$ when $x\to\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73243). Other [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/73243) might be of interest, too.

Answer (score 6):

Just use the fact that
$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e^{n\ln(1+\frac1n)}=e^{n\left(\frac1n-\frac{1}{2n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2})\right)}=e\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2n}+o(\frac1n)}=e\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+o\Bigl(\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigr)\right),$$and the result follows.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

$$\lim \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} n-\frac{n}{e}\left(1 +\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \lim \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1-\frac{1}{e}\left(1 +\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{\frac{1}{n}},$$ and use l'Hopital rule.

Comment: this answer is better and alot more simple. Good job.

Comment: @Bot, thanks for the comment :)

Comment: I don't know if this is better, since "use l'Hopital rule" is where all the work is.

Answer (score 3):

By the L'Hôpital's rule we obtain:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}n\left(1-\frac{1}{e}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{e-(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}}{ex}=-\frac{1}{e}\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\left(e^{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}\right)'=$$
$$=-\frac{1}{e}\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\left(\frac{1}{x(1+x)}-\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2}\right)=$$
$$=-\frac{1}{e}\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{x-(1+x)\ln(1+x)}{x^2+x^3}=$$
$$=-\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{1-\ln(1+x)-1}{2x+3x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{1}{2+3x}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

We have 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\bigg[1-\dfrac{n}{e}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n} \bigg]
=&
\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\bigg[\frac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{e}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n} \bigg]
\\
=&
\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg[\frac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{e}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n} \bigg]
\\
=&
\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\cdot \bigg[\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{e}\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n} \bigg]
\\
=&
\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\cdot \bigg[0-\dfrac{1}{e}e \bigg]
\\
=&
\lim_{n\to\infty}-n^2
=-\infty
\end{align}

Comment: I think the limit in the body is the correct one.

Comment: Edited my post please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n\bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{e}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n} \bigg)$$
First, let
$$a_n=\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n}\implies \log(a_n)=n \log\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)$$ that is to say
$$\log(a_n)=n\bigg(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+\frac{1}{3
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right) \bigg)=1-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{3 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Continuing with Taylor
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=e-\frac{e}{2 n}+\frac{11 e}{24 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$1-\dfrac{1}{e}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n}=\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{11}{24 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$n\bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{e}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n} \bigg)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{11}{24 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

For illustration, use your pocket calculator for $n=10$; the exact value is $10-\frac{25937424601}{1000000000 e}\approx 0.458155$ while the above expansion gives $\frac{109}{240}\approx 0.454167$.

Comment: Edited my post please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I'll present you the way I always approach these kinds of problems. You can or should be able to transform this into a rigorous argument. However, if you have any questions, feel free to ask them!

First, we try to find how quick the inside converges to $0$, i.e., how quick does this standard limit converge to $e$. Thereto, we take the logarithm of the stuff inside
$$\log\left(\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right) = n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right) = n\cdot\left(\frac1n - \frac{1}{2n^2} +O(n^{-3})\right) = 1 -\frac{1}{2n} +O(n^{-2})$$
Hence,
$$1-\frac1e\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n = 1-\frac1e\cdot \exp\left(1-\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2})\right) = 1 - \exp\left(-\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2})\right)$$
Finally, we need to multiply this with $n$. Can you finish this?

Since you added a bounty. Let me finish this for you. So in the end it boils down by finding the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(1 - \exp\left(-\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2})\right)\right)$$
Taylor states that
$$\exp\left(-\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2})\right) = 1 - \frac1{2n} + O(n^{-2})$$
And thus,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(1 - \exp\left(-\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2})\right)\right) =\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\frac1{2n} + O(n^{-2})\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12 +O(n^{-1}) =\frac12$$

Does this make sense?

Comment: Edited my post please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3534681), it is shown, using an elementary extension of Bernoulli's Inequality, that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1e\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right)^n=e^{-1/2}\tag1
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^n=e^{-1/2}\tag2
$$
we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^n-\left(\frac1e\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right)^n\right]=0\tag3
$$
$(1)$, $(2)$, and $\frac{x^n-y^n}{n(x-y)}=\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx^{n-k}y^{k-1}$ show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^n-\left(\frac1e\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right)^n}{n\left[\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)-\frac1e\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right]}=e^{-1/2}\tag4
$$
$(3)$ and $(4)$ imply that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left[\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)-\frac1e\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right]=0\tag5
$$
Adding $\frac12$ to both sides gives
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left[1-\frac1e\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right]=\frac12\tag6
$$

Answer (score -2):

Hint: try logarithms. $$f(n) - g(n) = \ln\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$$