# Limit exists or not? $\lim \limits_{n \to\infty}\ \left[n-\frac{n}{e}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right] $

Tags: limits

Determine whether or not the following limit exists, and find its value if it exists: $$\lim \limits_{n \to\infty}\ \left[n-\frac{n}{e}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right] $$

I think the limit of $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is $e$, but I am not sure I can use this or not in the limit calculation. Could you please help me to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: See also:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1093534
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3107466
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3534946

Comment: This question is about similar limit: [Limit of $x\left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x - e\right)$ when $x\to\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73243). Other [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/73243) might be of interest, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
n-\frac ne\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n&=n-\frac ne e^{n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)}\\\\
&=n-\frac ne e^{n\left(\frac1n -\frac{1}{2n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)}\\\\
&=n-n\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right) \\\\
&=\frac12+O\left(\frac1n\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Dr. MV Please check your calculation. Something's not right.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Friedrich, I've reviewed and it looks correct.  And I just checked WA and its result corroborates this solution.  What doesn't seem correct?  - Mark

Comment: @Dr. MV .Your second last line is equal to $ n-1/2-n O(1/n^2)=n-1/2+O(1/n)$ which is not  equal to the last line ,  although the limit is indeed $1/2.$

Comment: I made on purpose something very similar using a slightly different way. What I wanted to show is that we can get more than the limit itself. I hope and wish that you do not worry about my answer. Cheers.

Comment: @Dr. MV Your second but last line is $n - \frac 1 2 + O(\frac 1 n)$, which does not match with the lines before and after.

Comment: @friedrichphilipp There was a typographical error of omission that I have corrected now.  Thanks for your catching it.  -Mark

Comment: @user254665 There was a typographical error of omission that I have corrected.  Thanks for your catching it.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr. MV ,I was sure it was a typo but I was too tired  to   edit.

Comment: @user254665 I was too tired also apparently ;-))

Answer (score 2):

*This is very similar to Dr. MV's answer using a slightly different approach.*

Considering $$A_n=n-\frac{n}{e}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$ Let us first look at $$B_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$ Take the logarithm $$\log(B_n)=n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ Since $n$ is large, use Taylor for $\log(1+x)$ when $x$ is small and replace $x$ by $\frac 1n$. So, you have $$\log(B_n)=n\Big(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+\frac{1}{3 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\Big)=1-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{3 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Now $$B_n=e^{\log(B_n)}=e-\frac{e}{2 n}+\frac{11 e}{24 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Back to $A_n$ $$A_n=n-\frac n e\Big(e-\frac{e}{2 n}+\frac{11 e}{24 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \Big)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{11}{24 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

For illustration purposes, using $n=10$, $A_n\approx 0.458155$ while the above formula gives $\frac{109}{240}\approx 0.454167$.

Comment: I don't understand how $\exp(\log (B_n))=\exp\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{3n^2}+O(\frac{1}{n^3})\right)$ changes to $e-\frac{e}{2n}+\frac{11e}{24n^2}+O(\frac{1}{n^3})$. Could you kindly explain?

Comment: @StubbornAtom. It is again Taylor expansion.