# Limit of Sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty}[n-{\frac{n}{e}(1-\frac{1}{n})^n}]$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Find $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[n-\frac{n}{e}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right]. $

My Approach:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[n-\frac{n}{e}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right] = \lim_{n \to \infty} n \left[1-\frac{1}{e}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right] = \infty \times 0 = 0$$

Comment: $\infty \times 0 \neq 0$ (unless *sometimes* in the context of measure theory, but not here)

Comment: Besides the fact that "$\infty\times0$" is a straight *indeterminate*, why do you have $1-\frac{1}{e}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \to 0$ instead of $1-e^{-2}$?

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1093534/321264.

Comment: Yes, I got it now. I was missing the minus sign.

Comment: How could I approach if later term goes to zero i.e. if we put plus instead of minus.

Comment: You mean $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[n-\frac{n}{e}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right] $$?

Answer (score 4):

I got $\infty$ because $n - \frac{n}{e}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n= n\left(1-\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{e}\right)\to \infty$ because $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \to \frac{1}{e}$

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$a_n=n-\frac{n}{e}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$ you can do a nice work composing Taylor series. Here are the steps
$$A=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\implies \log(A)=n \log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$\log(A)=n\left(-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}-\frac{1}{3 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)=-1-\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{3 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{2 e n}-\frac{5}{24 e n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$a_n=n-\frac n e A=\left(1-\frac{1}{e^2}\right) n+\frac{1}{2 e^2}+\frac{5}{24 e^2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit.

But it also gives a shortcut *approximation* of the value of $a_n$. Take $n=10$; the exact result is
$$a_{10}=10-\frac{3486784401}{1000000000 e}\approx 8.71728$$ while the above truncated expression gives
$$a_{10}\sim 10-\frac{455}{48 e^2}\approx                     8.71713$$